# Why doesn't 'ItemsRead' in Invantive Data Access Point work anymore?

Tags: invantive-sql, invantive-dataaccesspoint

I've had a working update-script the last few months, but since 3 days ago the updating doesn't work anymore. The error returns that it can't find the table ItemsRead, but it's in the alternatives. My query returns the following error.

```
Invantive error: ValidationException itgeneor028
Unknown table 'ItemsRead'. Possible valid alternatives: ItemsRead, Items, Me, ItemPrices, Titles, ItemDetails, Lines, Units, Leads
```

What changed and how can I fix this? The client hasn't got any products on their website, so it's urgent. My query:

```
use <id>

select e.ID, e.Code, e.Description, e.SalesPrice, e.DefaultSalesPrice, e.ItemGroup, e.ItemGroupCode, e.ItemGroupDescription, e.Notes, e.PictureName, e.PictureUrl, e.Stock, e.Unitdescription, e.IsWebshopItem, i.Class_01, i.Class_02, i.Class_03 from exactonlinerest..items e left join logistics.ItemsRead i on e.ID = i.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is a little unclear, yes. The problem is: it can't find `*Logistics*.ItemsRead`. `ItemsRead` is okay. Hence that object is in the list of alternatives.

There was a rename of the objects by the way: `Items` and `ItemsRead` had been accidentally swapped. That is corrected now, so now you have to use this query:

```
select e.ID
,      e.Code
,      e.Description
,      i.SalesPrice
,      i.DefaultSalesPrice
,      i.ItemGroup
,      i.ItemGroupCode
,      i.ItemGroupDescription
,      i.Notes
,      i.PictureName
,      i.PictureUrl
,      i.Stock
,      i.Unitdescription
,      i.IsWebshopItem
,      e.Class_01
,      e.Class_02
,      e.Class_03
from   exactonlinerest..items e
join   exactonlinerest..ItemsRead i
on     e.ID = i.ID
```